# How to execute a command when internet is back

Tags: networking, scripting, monitoring, internet

Sometimes my wifi is connected to router but my router is not connected to internet. How can I execute a command when my internet is back (from command line)? I want to execute:

```
mpg123 /home/user/file.mp3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
    ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        break
    else
        echo 'No internet'
    fi
    sleep 1
done
mpg123 /home/user/file.mp3
```

It will show you 'no internet' message if there is no ping response. And if it gets the response it will execute your command and quit.

Answer (score 1):

You could periodically ping a website and execute your command when ping returns success. Something like the following...

```
result=1
while [ $result -ne 0 ]
do
   ping -c 1 www.google.com
   result=$?
   sleep 5
done
mpg123 /home/user/file.mp3
```

Comment: Use `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null 2>&1` as @malyy has suggested